# mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

This `mysqli_fetch_array` not returning values. Checked it for SQL errors, none found. some error in PHP or functions I guess. Please help me correct it.

```
$login = login($username, $password);
if ($login == false) {
    $errors[] = "That username and password     combination is incorrect";
}

// validate login
function login($username, $password){
    $user_id = id_from_username($username);
    echo $user_id;
    $password = md5($password);
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = "SELECT `password` FROM `user_data` WHERE `username` = '$username' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

    if ($row[0] == $password) {
        echo "Login successful";
        return $user_id;
    }
    else{
        echo "Login not successful";
        return false;
    }
}

// user id from username
function id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `user_data` WHERE      `username` = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    return $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Your code is super vulnerable to SQL injections. Take a look at prepared statements! Also don't use MD5 for hashing users passwords! it isn't secure anymore

Comment: Also, have you looked for any php errors?

Comment: `id_from_username` does not have access to `$conn` + what @Isaac said ;p

Comment: It looks more that the code is incomplete. `$conn` must have been defined somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve]. That helps everybody.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As Lawrence correctly pointed out I missed the variable scope issue. `mysqli_query` does not have access to `$conn` variable.

---

Try to check the number of returned rows in the `$result`:

```
echo $result->num_rows;
```

Or print it to the log if you have some. Not sure how you are checking `mysqli_fetch_array` does not return values - try `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

Few further recommendations:

- Both queries in your question select from the same table - `user_data` - it is pretty inefficient to do it separately (unless `id_from_username` is commonly used elsewhere), I'd merge that into one query to select it at once:

  SELECT `user_id`, `password` FROM `user_data` WHERE ...
- Using `mysqli_query` and concatenating user input into the query is usually a bad idea. Not sure what your `sanitize` function does but I'd still use variable binding instead, even `mysqli` supports that with `mysqli_prepare`, see [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
- Based on your code you are storing passwords in database using `md5`. This is a very bad practice. PHP provides very nice functions [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) and [password_verify](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) since PHP 5.5.0, they will handle password hashing for you and make your application a lot more secure.

Comment: Missed the variable scope issue.

Comment: plus 1 to what Lawrence said. You make good valid points but how do these FIX the OP's issue?

Comment: Thank you.. it works, I missed the function to connect dB within those functions, and if there are any references to making the code secure, please suggest.

Comment: Oh yeah Lawrence, totally missed that :-$